# Do I lose speed if I extend a 3.1 USB-C cable?

Tags: file-transfer, speed, cable, usb-c

I would like to extend a 0.5m USB-C 3.1 cable with a female to male 2m USB-C 3.1 cable. Do I lose data transfer speed if I do this? If yes, can I somehow quantify the loss of speed?

Comment: 2 Meters should be OK for the speeds concerned. I commonly use this length of cable (USB and other) without issue. Make sure the cable is top quality.  I have a cheap 10 foot (3+ meters) that did not work well

Comment: Even further with special cables>>>>https://www.newnex.com/usb-3-1-type-c-active-cable.php

Comment: I am going to post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good 2 meter cable should be fine for the speeds concerned. I commonly use this length of cable (for USB and other) without issue.

Make sure the cable is top quality. Cable quality and terminations are important in maintaining signal quality .

I have a cheap 10 foot (3+ meters) cable (poorly made and poor materials) that did not work well